# UILabel on UITableViewCell doesn't appear after insert new Item in fetchedResultsController project

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My project runs on XCode7 with **CoreData** and `fetchedResultsController`

There's a UILabel in the `UITableViewCell`, when i clicked "+" to create a new Item and the UILabel shows the name.

But the name(Green label) doesn't appear very first time i run the app and add insert the the item. Not sure what's the reason?

Here are the code and picture:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            NSIndexPath *indexPathT = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
            EventMO *event = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPathT];
                TargetCell * cell = (TargetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TargetCell"];
            cell.name.text = event.name;
            if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TargetCell class]]) {
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            }
DLog(@"%@ ------ %u",cell.contentView.subviews,indexPath.row);
            cell.name.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            return cell;
}
```

logout:"

```
<UILabel: 0x7d8f8bc0; frame = (-42 -21; 42 21); text = '123'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 10; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7d8f8ae0>>"
) ------ 0
```

**TargetCell.h/.m**

```
@interface TargetCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;

@end

#import "TargetCell.h"
@implementation TargetCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By guess is that tableview is reusing cells and sometimes it reuses the one that doesn't contain blue label. Can you post full cellForIndex path method?

Comment: Edited, there's only one "prototype Cells".

Answer (score 0):

My problem is i have a `AddEventViewController` controller which present from `HomeViewController`. After fill the event names etc, then save directly by `[context save:&error]` and then `[self.dismissViewController:  addEventViewController];` cased the issue happened. I guess maybe UITableView is not ready to update

```
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

After i change to order of `dissmissViewController` and  `[context save:&error]`, everything works like normal.